# pass a model from View to Controller using ext.ajax.request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I am new at using ExtJS and right now i'm trying to call a Controller Method using ext.ajax.request and pass a model as a parameter.

however once the Method is called, the parameter returns NULL

EmployeeModel.cs:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

CODE:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    using (GLContext db = new GLContext ())
    {
        var employee = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id  == emp.Id);

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
var emp = empGrid.getStore().getAt(context.rowIdx);

var newEmp = Ext.create('EmpModel', {
    EmployeeId: emp.data.EmployeeId,
    FirstName: context.newValues.FirstName,
    LastName: context.newValues.FirstName,
    OfficeLocation: context.newValues.FirstName,
    PhoneNumber: context.newValues.FirstName
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Home/UpdateEmployee',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        emp: newEmp.data
    },
});
```

I've added newEmp.data to watchlist and it has value

```
newEmp.data: Object
    EmployeeId:2
    FirstName:"sergyguk"
    LastName:"serthyuk"
    OfficeLocation:"rthgyuk"
    PhoneNumber:"drhtyguk"
```

but when it calls the Controller method, it returns an error because the (Employee emp) parameter is null

I appreciate any help on this
Thanks

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(emp.data)`

Comment: thank you for the response @Curiousdev, however it still gives me NULL Employee :(

Comment: When using Ext.data.model, don't access the `data` property directly. Use [`get`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-get) for getting a single property value, [`getData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-getData) to get all data and [`set`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set) for setting single or multiple property values.

Comment: hi @MarthyM, i replaced the data by getData and emp.getData() gave me what i want. but still when passed to the controller method, still is null

Comment: I agree with @Curiousdev. Try to find the problem by logging each step of constructing the parameter value. Something like: `var employeeData = emp.getData(); var employeeDataJson = JSON.stringify(employeeData); console.log(emp, employeeData, employeeDataJson);`.

Comment: hi @MarthyM, all of the mentioned are giving me data, in fact the correct data. stringify, getdata() and console.log gives me all the correct data with no problem, the only problem is when i put a breakpoint on my Controller model and check the passed parameter, it is null

Comment: You can also view the request in your browser developer tools (ctrl + shift + I) in 'network' tab. If the request parameter is filled correctly, the problem is server-side.

Comment: I ended up just using @Curiousdev suggestion, JSON.stringify(emp.data). and just changed my method param to string public void UpdateEmployee(string emp), then just convert to Employee model. I just know if it's a good practice though :(